# How to find a match between any partial value in column A and any value column B? And extract?

Tags: regex, list, dataframe

I have two columns in a pandas DataFrame, both containing also a lot of null values. Some values in column B, exist **partially** in a field (or multiple fields) in columns A. I want to check if this value of B exists in A, and if so, seperate this value and add as a new row in column A

Example:

```
Column A   | Column B

black bear | null
black box  | null
red fox    | null
red fire   | null
green tree | null
null       | red
null       | yellow
null       | black
null       | red
null       | green
```

And I want the following:

```
Column A
black
bear
box
red
fire
fox
yellow
green
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to get this result? I have tried using regex (`re.match`), but I am struggling with the fact that I do not have a fixed pattern but a variable (namely, any value in column B) This is my effort:

```
    import re

    list_A= df['Column A'].values.tolist()
    list_B= df['Column B'].values.tolist()

    for i in list_A:
      for j in list_B:
        if i != None:
          if re.match('{j}.+', i) : 
          ...
```

***Note: the columns are over 2500 rows long.***

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly that you want to split the value of `b` from the value in `a` whenever `b` is found in `a`, and then stored the separated values separately, then how about trying the following?

```
import re

list_A = df['Column A'].values.tolist()
list_B = df['Column B'].values.tolist()
list_of_separated_values = []

for a in list_a:
   for b in list_b:
       if b in a:
           list_of_separated_values.extend([val for val in re.split('({})'.format(b),a) if not val])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regex question. You have your data in a dataframe, use the dataframe functionality to fix it.

Assuming `data_frame` is your pandas DataFrame.

```
# filter the DataFrame to just those with `null` in Column A
filtered = data_frame[data_frame["Column A"].isnull()]
# in the filtered table, assign Column B to Column A
filtered["Column A"] = filtered["Column B"]
# set Column B to null/None (I'm assuming you want this or this step can be skipped)
filtered["Column B"] = None
print(data_frame)
```